# Which side is positive?

Tags: capacitor

I have this old capacitor without any indication showing the polarity.

[image] [image] [image]

How can I determine which side is positive?

Comment: Can you put an image of the side, too? Sometimes, they have a rim or thread on the positive side.

Comment: Seems to be an collar or ring on the body facing the camera. If everything else fails, hook up to your lab power supply, set the current limit really low and see which direction allows it to charge up.

Comment: For electrolytic capacitors, the outside can is usually negative.

Comment: The other pictures didn’t download. Sorry, i just updated it

Comment: Where was this capacitor inserted, to what kind of circuit, doing what purpose? If the point is to replace a capacitor, it may be easier to determine polarity from the circuit, not the capacitor. The circuit may reveal the capacitor polarity, but it may also reveal if it is not even a polarized capacitor, but a non-polarized capacitor.

Comment: 100 uF for a non polarized capacitor ? It’s for a jukebox PSU

Comment: Measure the voltage across the wiring terminals with the capacitor disconnected. That will give you the polarity. The voltage may be an average reading of a rectified waveform so rate the capacitor at least 1.5 times the DC reading.

Answer (score 4):

The end with the indentation all the way around the can, as shown on the left side of the part in the first photo, is the positive (+) end of the cap, the anode.

Answer (score 2):

The lead rivetted to the can is negative.

The lead insulated from the can is positive.